# How to fill a register without entering in insert mode?

Tags: vim, vim-registers

I'd like to optimize the initialization of a register when I use it in a macro.

I usually initialize my register by doing something like `q:i0 <Esc> "eyiw:q`, but I think there is a better way... I'd like to avoid entering insert mode if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qaq` (start and immediately stop recording) clears register `a`.

So, to clear register `q` and start recording (e.g. a recursive macro), use `qqqqq...`

---

From the command-line, you can also do:

```
:let @a = ''
```

or

```
:call setreg('a', '')
```